# extjs calendar 4.1.1 restricted time slot for booking

Tags: extjs, calendar, extjs4.1

I am using extjs 4.1.1 calendar ( scheduler ) for keeping the track of people schedule but i can into trouble as i cant figure out how to restrict the booking time slot for individual

example.

User A can book the slot between 3pm to 4 pm on monday to wednesday.

User B Can book slots between 1 am to 5 am on monday and saturday

image link 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuCVV.png

Comment: Actually this is a UX component included in the basic library distribution: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/calendar/index.html.  I think the correlation is close enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be more complicated than you really want to work with, but we had to do this in our app, the only real way to do it is to override their Extensible.calendar.dd.DropZone class and overwrite the onNodeOver method with your own logic, hope you understand the Extjs well :) :

```
Ext.override("Extensible.calendar.dd.DropZone", {

onNodeOver : function(n, dd, e, data){
        //change anything in this logic with the logic you want....
        //but preferrably, don't change anything and use callOverridden and then add your stuff as extras
        var D = Extensible.Date,
            start = data.type == 'eventdrag' ? n.date : D.min(data.start, n.date),
            end = data.type == 'eventdrag' ? D.add(n.date, {days: D.diffDays(data.eventStart, data.eventEnd)}) :
                D.max(data.start, n.date);

        if(!this.dragStartDate || !this.dragEndDate || (D.diffDays(start, this.dragStartDate) != 0) || (D.diffDays(end, this.dragEndDate) != 0)){
            this.dragStartDate = start;
            this.dragEndDate = D.add(end, {days: 1, millis: -1, clearTime: true});
            this.shim(start, end);

            var range = Ext.Date.format(start, this.dateFormat);

            if(D.diffDays(start, end) > 0){
                end = Ext.Date.format(end, this.dateFormat);
                range = Ext.String.format(this.dateRangeFormat, range, end);
            }
            var msg = Ext.String.format(data.type == 'eventdrag' ? this.moveText : this.createText, range);
            data.proxy.updateMsg(msg);
        }
        return this.dropAllowed;
    }
});
```